# check if table exist/created already in BB 10 cascades

Tags: sqlite, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I am creating a table in BB 10 cascades like

```
  const QString query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS push (seqnum INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, pushdate TEXT, type TEXT, pushtime TEXT,alertId TEXT, extension TEXT, content BLOB, unread INTEGER);");
```

now how can i check if table created/existed  already? Is there any query for that?

help me,
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='table_name';`

This will return 0, if the table doesn't exist, 1 if it does.

Comment: QSqlQuery sqlQuery(query, SQLConnection()); and sqlQuery.next() returns the number? if you dint mind can you please post complete method...i am new to BB 10

Comment: In BB10 you can use bool QSqlQuery::exec ( const QString & query ); This will return false, if the table doesn't exist, true if it does: http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/qsqlquery.html#exec

Comment: but it is returning Zero always, I am like this                                    int exits=sqlQuery.next();